# subversion error : Can't open file '/var/svn/mobilesync/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied

Tags: linux, security, svn, admin

We have a repository running on subversion 1.6.6 on Ubuntu server. While adding a new file to the working copy and committing it to the repo, we get the error

```
Can't open file '/var/svn/mobilesync/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied
```

What is the issue and what can I do about it ? Is it a matter of a lock created by a previous process instance that didn't get removed because of some error ?

Thank you,

**UPDATE**
Here were the commands that I used to create the repo

```
1) sudo svnadmin create myrepo
2) sudo chown  www-data:www-data myrepo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this problem by changing the second command

```
sudo chown -R www-data:subversion myrepo
```

and then I was able to commit my files.

Comment: which parts are to be customized for my usage?

Comment: @Maysam `www-data` should be replaced with the user you want to own the files, `subversion` should be replaced with the group, and `myrepo` should be replaced with your SVN repository.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when i imported another repository into my own svn server. And the following command solved my issue:

```
$sudo chown -R www-data:www-data myrepo
```

fyi, you need to log in your svn server, check the permission of existed repositories, in my case it's www-data etc. and use 'chown' to change the owner and group of your repository in terms of owner setting of your other repositories.

-R is used as recursive option.
"myrepo" means the name of your repository.

i think "www-data" is used for apache server which is used inside my svn server.

Hope it helps.